# How do I generate a tnsnames.ora file to connect to an Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle

I have installed Oracle 11g, and I can connect as `sysman` to the Oracle database, but there is no `tnsnames.ora` file that I can find.

Do I need to generate the tnsnames.ora file myself? If so, where do I place it? If not, how does Oracle generate it for me?  If I do need to generate it, what is the appropriate syntax for the file?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can easily create a tnsnames.ora [text] file.  It should be in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/ and should look something like this:

```
 ORATST=
 (description=
   (address_list=
     (address = (protocol = TCP)(host = fu.bar)(port = 1521))
   )
 (connect_data =
   (service_name=oratst)
 )
)
```

Comment: Good answer, although I found that I had to name my file `$HOME/.tnsnames.ora`; the path suggested in the answer seemed to be ignored by sqlplus.

Comment: @DuffJ then something is wrong with your environment.

Answer (score 12):

The default directory for a tnsnames.ora file is

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/<version>/<dbname>/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
```

Contents:

```
<alias> = (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <ip>)(PORT = <port>))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = <dbname>)
    )
  )
```

- `alias`: you can choose this and use it as connection string later on.
- `port`: the default is 1521

More info here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm

Comment: The default directory is nothing of the sort. It's relative to `$ORACLE_HOME` and therefore will be `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` (where `$ORACLE_HOME` can be multiple different directories where there's more than one Oracle install/patch level) or can be overrided by the `$TNS_ADMIN` environment variable. It's completely up to the user where the software resides.

Comment: Honestly it is the default on a linux system... If you don't touch a thing it will be put there... thus being the default. But $ORACLE_HOME if not tampered with is indeed a better solution.

Comment: I have run Oracle on literally hundreds of Linux systems and that is NOT the default, nor is there such a thing. Perhaps you mean that's the example in the documentation, well they had to choose something. There is no Linux distro that I know of that has a /u01 filesystem "by default", you must have created it and told Oracle to use it!

Answer (score 4):

If your OS is ***Windows 10***, you can find `tnsnames.ora` file in the following unc path:

```
C:\app\myAccount\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
```

Where `myAccount` is your Windows account name.

Comment: In other words, it's `%ORACLE_HOME%\NETWORK\ADMIN`, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Remember Oracle by default store tnsnames.ora in the $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin directory on UNIX operating systems and in the %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin directory on Windows operating systems.

Comment: $ORACLE_HOME wasn't working for me on my environment, so knowing the full path really helped... just knowing it was in C:\app\... gave me the start I needed and I was able to track it down from there. Saved me hours of searching!

Answer (score 2):

`$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` is the directory where `tnsnames.ora` file is created by DBCA and/or NetCA.

`$ORACLE_HOME` is a path like `/u01/app ...`, it is an OFA compliant path that the installler uses as default if not overriden by installer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know the `tnsnames.ora` needs to be placed at the
`<ORA_INSTALL_FOLDER>\product\11.1.0\client_1\network\admin\` folder

Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm)