# Connecting to an 11g Standard Database (Local)

Tags: oracle, installation, oracle-sql-developer

I've installed 11g Standard on a VM, it's going to be connected to from other Computers/Users. It installs successfully but I'm not really sure how to create my first database on it (using SQL Developer).

I'm trying to connect with SQL developer, but I'm not really sure of the parameters? Should I be able to connect at this stage? What do I enter for Username/Password etc...?

I've seen guides but they are for Express Edition. This is on a Windows 8 64 Bit VM Btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you have the database software installed. Here is the [11.2 Installation Quick Guide for Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24283/toc.htm) Here is the [11.2 documentation home](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/portal.portal_db?selected=1&frame=#new_to_oracle_database_11g). Now you need to install a database instance and start a listener. Then you need to create a connection in SQL Developer to the database instance.

Some essential tools during this are SQLPlus on the server. Enterprise Manager Database Control `http://host.domain:1158/em/` You will need to Remote Desktop into the server to perform database setup tasks as the SYS user. On the server DOS window:

```
sqlplus /nolog
SQL>connect sys@myinstance AS SYSDBA
enter your password.
```

If you did not create a database instance during the install, use [Database Configuration Assistant (DBCA)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/create002.htm). A universal approach for client connectivity is to use a [tnsnames.ora](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28326/how-do-i-generate-a-tnsnames-ora-file-to-connect-to-an-oracle-database) file located in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`. The parameters for this become the connection parameters in SQL Developer.

In a DOS window on the server, run the [listener control](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28316/listenercfg.htm) with

```
lsnrctl help
lsnrctl status   tells you which instances are running.
```

Once you have the instance created, create a new tablespace to hold your tables. Then create a user that will be the schema owner of the tables associated with that tablespace. It is a good practice to create a separate user for each person in addition to the schema owner. Then create tables, views, stored procedures, etc.

Hope this is enough to get you started. The links are good reads.